# How to define a function does not return or return void in scala

Tags: scala

With more and more confused raised up, I even find that I can not understand simple Function definition in Scala:

If I just want to define a function doing nothing but some unuseful addition, how can I do that like this:

```
def nothing(a:Int, b:Int) = {
    a = a+1; b=b+1;
}
```

**What I want is add 1 to a and b and return nothing or void.**

I kinda feel the more I learnt, the more I begin unfamiliar with, even to those I learnt before, this is terrible.

Comment: You can't reassign method parameters. You can declare new vals, though: `val a_ = a + 1; val b_ = b + 1`

Comment: @ChrisMartin Thanks, so you mean that I have to define two variable to copy the parameters and do the addition?  And could you tell me how can I return void?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your question boils down to two parts:

1) How do I define function which returns nothing? Pretty easy, just encode it to type signature, Unit is the scala way to say void (they're the same actually, java function that returns void will return Unit in scala world):

```
scala> def foo(x: Int): Unit = x * x
foo: (x: Int)Unit

scala> foo(1)

scala>
```

Previously scala encouraged so called *procedure* definition (see, no equals sign):

```
scala> def foo(x: Int) { x * x }
foo: (x: Int)Unit

scala> foo(2)

scala>
```

But it's error prone and thus discouraged.

2) How do I alter primitive that was passed into the function? You can't, scala, as well as Java does not allow this and it's for a great good.

Comment: Thanks,  I wonder why it does not work once I add a if else block like: def max(a:Int, b:Int):Unit={ if(a>b) {val a_ = a+1} else { val b_=b+1}}

Comment: @Kuan what would be the point of that? you create a local `val` named `a_` or `b_` that you don't use. Since you're not doing anything with this local `val` it's not useful to do something like that.

Comment: @Jesper Thanks for asking. This is just for study purpose to understand usage / concept of scala.

Comment: "Avoid the procedure syntax, as it tends to be confusing for very little gain in brevity." - https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/declarations.html#procedure-syntax

Comment: @om-nom-nom Can you please explain why is it considered error prone in the 2nd example?  I'm new to scala, after coming from c++ background.  I'm having trouble with this new way of thinking and some of the things I find seems to be simply more opinionated rather than a legit reason.  This is just my opinion though but I'd like to learn more behind the logic behind the recommended style when using scala.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris and om-nom said, you cannot alter primitive passed as arguments to a function, and will need to declare new vals. Also, you can specify the return type of your variable by appending `: Unit` (or any valid type) after the parameters, in the signature, as following:

```
 def nothing(a:Int, b:Int): Unit = { val new_a = a+1; val new_b = b+1 }
```

Note that the implicit type of your function was already `Unit`, i.e void in scala.

Comment: Thanks, I wonder why it does not work once I add a if else block like:   def max(a:Int, b:Int):Unit={ if(a>b) {val a_ = a+1} else { val b_=b+1}}

Comment: @Bacon ending variable names with _ is a land mine, and Kuan stepped on it. Please, don't do this.

Comment: @Kuan Always include whitespace around `=`.

Comment: @Kuan it's because "variable_name_=" is a syntax to generate setter, see http://dustinmartin.net/getters-and-setters-in-scala/ for details.

Comment: Right. `def max(a:Int, b:Int):Unit={ if(a>b) {val new_a = a+1} else { val new_b = b+1 } }` is working

Comment: @ChrisMartin it's quite arguable rule

Answer (score 1):

If you just came from C++, Unit is the keyword your looking for. It works exactly as void regarding function return.

It seems to me the issue here is that still don't understand functional programming. It is not possible to change value of passed parameters:

```
def nothing(a:Int, b:Int) = {
    a = a+1; b=b+1; // this won't work
}
```

Instead, you should return new values with the result operation. In this case, you should sum 1 to a and b and return both using a Tuple2. You can do this using the following sintaxes:

```
def nothing(a:Int, b:Int) = {
    (a + 1, b + 1)
}
```

or

```
def nothing(a:Int, b:Int) = {
    Tuple2(a + 1, b + 1)
}
```

or

```
def nothing(a:Int, b:Int) = {
    Tuple2[Int, Int](a + 1, b + 1)
}
```

Comment: It doesn't change a lot, but [@Kuan declared Java and Javascript as their background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31998382/298389)

Comment: @WilsondeCarvalho thanks for add extra info of functional programming, it is helpful to me to understand why the parameter can not be modified.

Comment: @Kuan, this book helped me a lot when I first started in Scala, five years ago: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf

Comment: @Wilson de Carvalho Thanks, I have printed this book, it is right on my desk, I read half of it by now, feel the starting part is really good, but when dive in, it hides some detail which need to be told to beginner. That is why I got so much confuse.

Comment: @Kuan I also read a few more books that may be interesting for you. One of those I enjoyed most is Programming in Scala, written by Martin Odersky. Functional Programming in Scala is also a good guide. I read it when it was on the Manning Early Access Program (MEAP). The last one may be more appropriate for your case, since you are struggling with FP, but I recommend both. Good luck.

Comment: yeah, an example of function that would return Unit:     


def eat(): Unit = {
      println("yum yum, I am eating")
}